# Time Series Penalty Function cplex

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, pyomo

Somewhat new to OR and was wondering if there's a way to do this problem in pyomo/cplex linearly.

Say we have a set of pegs x1.....xn and a set of days t1....tn. We want to select a subset of pegs for each of the days.

However, I want to add a penalty factor such that if x1 is in the selection for day ti then its more likely to be in the selection for ti+1. But if x1 is in the selection for day ti and ti+1 then there's no additional benefit for being in the selection for ti+2. Is this possible to create linearly?

Comment: Please move this question to the Operations Research site.